# How to use a shell scripts in a cron

Tags: linux, cron

I decided to make autorun through **cron**. In the terminal after writing **crontab -e** opens the editor in which i write

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=roma
HOME=/
*/1 * * * * root run-parts  /home/roma/autorun.sh
```

In the inside to  **autorun.sh** it is written:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd image
mirage 8475.jpg
```

This script opens the image in the directory **image**

Then I save the file. I'm waiting about 1 minute, but nothing happens. What is the problem?

Comment: Have you made the script executable? chmod +x /home/roma/autorun.sh

Comment: chmod +x /home/roma/autorun.sh - did not  help me.

Comment: Where does the image folder reside? If you run 'mirage /full/path/to/image/8475.jpg' does the command work?

Comment: What is mirage? Programs started from cron are **not** connected to a terminal, so any interactive program should fail for either no DISPLAY if graphic of EOF on stdin if command line

Comment: mirage /full/path/to/image/8475.jpg -  working.

Comment: Then you should look at the comment by @SergeBallesta

Comment: I chack  cat /var/log/syslog. I found line " Mar  8 14:52:01 roma CRON[7165]: (roma) CMD (/home/roma/autorun.sh)"

Comment: Mirage is  an image viewer.

Comment: What is it you are trying to accomplish by triggering an image viewer once every minute? If you are trying to set an rotating desktop background or something similar, there are other ways to do that. A quick google search might be of help.